# Change position of rows in xlswriter python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I am using below code

```
    from io import BytesIO
    with BytesIO() as b:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(b, engine='xlsxwriter')
        default_template.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Master',  index=False)
        workbook  = writer.book
        worksheet = writer.sheets['Master']
        header_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True,'text_wrap': True,'valign': 'top','fg_color': '#FFFF00','border': 1})
        for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
            if value in required:
                worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
        writer.save()
        return HttpResponse(b.getvalue(), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

Which gives me output like Picture 1
[image]

However i want the output excel file to be like pic2
[image]

Any help :)

Comment: This doesn't look like an exact transpose. Are you sure the output you've pasted here is what you actually want?

Comment: @MayankPorwal yes.

Comment: @MayankPorwal i just need to change the positions of rows , thats not transpose i guess (I am kinda new), could you please suggest anything?